# using jQuery to dynamicly reload or switch external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, external, reload

I have a webpage where I have an external js file that animates some divs. I want to place a button on the page that reloads the js file from the start so it stops the function and starts from the beginning. 
I tried giving the script tag the id "animation" and then using the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".button").click(function()
{

    $("#animation").attr('src','map.js');

});
}
);
```

Needless to say it did not work. Wondering how to do this correctly.

Comment: Have you tried using `.load('map.js');`?

Comment: Yes but no luck. Would this not just load it twice and not stop the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **really not a good thing to do**, much better to make a function to start and stop the animation. But if you *really really* have to:

```
$(".button").click(function( e ) { 

    //change this to the id of your script
    $('#the_script').remove();

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = 'the_script';
    //the script's source here
    script.src = 'test_js.js';
    script.type ='text/javascript';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

});
```

Comment: I see. Yes I wouldn't normally do this but the page has different animations that need to be restarted. The content in a particular div area is being controlled by a different js file and each animation needs to have a reload button without reloading the rest of the page.

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
  {








count = 0;

$(".button").click(function()
{
 
 

 

    //obviously to target a specific script just change this selector
    $('map.js').each(function() {

        var js_src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', '');
        reload( this, js_src );
    }
);
}
);

function reload( el, js_src ){

    count++;

    $( el ).attr('src', js_src + "?"+ count );
    
 }
    






});  thanks for the help. I cannot seem to get it working. I think I am not closing the functions wrong or getting confused somewhere.

Comment: I thought of a better way of doing it, see the edited answer above

Comment: Brilliant.Seems so simple when you put it like this. Thanks Nick